# Rails Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffold

**Weird error. I'm a newby to rails. From a new install of rails I connected to an oracle db and then ran:**

```
jruby script/generate scaffold job oid:integer userid:integer name:string status:integer
```

**Without doing anything else I started up the server and entered a new job and then I get this error:**

```
Routing Error

job_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"show", :id=>#<Job id: #<BigDecimal:d55a0f,'10000.0',1(8)>, oid: #<BigDecimal:10bb83e,'1324.0',4(8)>, userid: #<BigDecimal:6d234c,'1234.0',4(8)>, name: "asdfadsf", status: #<BigDecimal:1286c71,'1234.0',4(8)>, created_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37", updated_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37">}, expected: {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"show"}, diff: {:id=>#<Job id: #<BigDecimal:853e51,'10000.0',1(8)>, oid: #<BigDecimal:1be4050,'1324.0',4(8)>, userid: #<BigDecimal:adb165,'1234.0',4(8)>, name: "asdfadsf", status: #<BigDecimal:15978e7,'1234.0',4(8)>, created_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37", updated_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37">}
```

**Even though it throws the error it still creates the record. When I try to view the record I get the following stack, which is really the same error.**

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Jobs#show

Showing app/views/jobs/show.html.erb where line #22 raised:

edit_job_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"edit", :id=>#<Job id: #<BigDecimal:18caa36,'10000.0',1(8)>, oid: #<BigDecimal:1fac733,'1324.0',4(8)>, userid: #<BigDecimal:12c1472,'1234.0',4(8)>, name: "asdfadsf", status: #<BigDecimal:f25f89,'1234.0',4(8)>, created_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37", updated_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37">}, expected: {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"edit"}, diff: {:id=>#<Job id: #<BigDecimal:1b9cdfc,'10000.0',1(8)>, oid: #<BigDecimal:1829097,'1324.0',4(8)>, userid: #<BigDecimal:e2d663,'1234.0',4(8)>, name: "asdfadsf", status: #<BigDecimal:691ccf,'1234.0',4(8)>, created_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37", updated_at: "2009-12-15 00:49:37">}
Extracted source (around line #22):

19: </p>
20: 
21: 
22: <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_job_path(@job) %> |
23: <%= link_to 'Back', jobs_path %>
RAILS_ROOT: /opt/code/import

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:426:in `raise_named_route_error'
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:387:in `generate'
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/url_rewriter.rb:205:in `rewrite_path'
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/url_rewriter.rb:184:in `rewrite_url'
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/url_rewriter.rb:162:in `rewrite'
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:634:in `url_for'
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:85:in `url_for'
(eval):16:in `edit_job_path'
/opt/code/import/app/views/jobs/show.html.erb:22:in `_run_erb_app47views47jobs47show46html46erb'
/opt/code/import/app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:18:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"10000"}
Show session dump

Response

Headers:

{"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache",
 "Content-Type"=>"text/html"}
```

**When I remove the "edit_job_path" method the error disappears so I know it's just having an issue rendering the route, but I'm not sure why because it seems to have the correct info. I mean this is a boilerplate scaffold so.... Thanks in advance for any help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your ID field is a `BigDecimal`, where it should be an `Integer`. It is interpreting a number such as "1234.54" separated into two parts, something like `{:action => "1234", :format => "54" }`.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks Ryan! I realized there was something going on with that BigDecimal after I posted it, but wasn't exactly sure what. You nailed it. This was happing because I was using JRuby, which I don't need to do, so I'm switching back to a non-Java Ruby VM.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this line in your config/routes.rb:

```
map.resources :jobs
```

Also run "rake routes" to see what routes are available. The *path and *url methods are generated by named routes and resources you define in the routes.rb file. More info [here](http://guides.rails.info/routing.html#restful-routing-the-rails-default).